# Loop through files and convert BMP files to JPG

Tags: files, mogrify

I have a folder of images. All have the JPG extension but when running `file` against a few, they're coming back as bitmap e.g.

```
25818.jpg: PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 357 x 500 x 24
```

My question is how would I loop through all the images, check whether it's a bitmap file and then convert it to a JPG?

The command I'd use in a single case would be the following but not sure how I'd do the checks and loop through the files

```
mogrify -format jpg 25818.jpg
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to keep the original files?

Comment: Nope - happy for them to be deleted

Comment: Do you trust `file` to determine the format?

Comment: `identify` would be safer for determining the image format (if I remember correctly, it was a decade since I used ImageMagick).

Answer (score 3):

```
while IFS='' read -rd '' filename; do 
  [[ $(file -b --mime-type "$filename") = image/x-ms-bmp ]] \
      && mogrify -format jpg "$filename"
done < <(LC_ALL=C find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.jpg' -print0)
```

will work, provided that your version of `file` outputs `image/x-ms-bmp` when given a BMP file as argument of `file -b --mime-type`. Otherwise, you have to modify the script.

Many users would settle for the simpler version

```
for filename in ./*.jpg; do 
  [[ $(file -b --mime-type "$filename") = image/x-ms-bmp ]] \
      && mogrify -format jpg "$filename"
done
```

which, however, would fail in some circumstances: 1) if you have a *very* large number of files with *very* long names (say, 30000 filenames of average length) 2) if your filenames contain really weird characters.

The first version is guaranteed against such rare inconveniencies.

Comment: :) I wasn't chatting... I was simply suggesting you use `find` the right way, that is use the built-in `-exec` but I see you misread my comments. Never mind then.

Answer (score 1):

With `exiftool`, you could do:

```
exiftool -q -r -ext jpg -if '
  $FileType eq "BMP" and !print "$Directory/$FileName\0"' . |
  xargs -r0 mogrify -format jpg
```